# Normalize perceived brightness using lightness from hue wheel value (hsl)

Tags: javascript, colors

I've created a hue color slider to choose a highlighting color for custom highlighters.

Some colors, however, like yellow, are perceived as being very bright, compared to say purple which appears dark. As I understand, this is because even though the screen is emitting the same total amount of brightness in terms of RGB, our retina picks the different colors up differently, making some appear brighter than others.

I would like to 'normalize' this color wheel according to HSL. It would be nice to have a function that takes in a hue and spits out the adjustment needed to lightness to make everything perceivably even.

I'll appreciate the pointers!
Thanks

Comment: Just forget HSL and other "computer" colour space (which uses constant range on all hue). (and also the angle of H is arbitrary). You can convert to CIELab or CIE LCH which should have correct L. But it will be trickier to get the L range per H or to do operation and remaining to sRGB colour space. And you should consider which colour space you are working in. RGB is not a colour space. PC historically used sRGB, Digital cinema DCI P4, Apple now is using Apple P3, phones and TV tell you they have better saturation (so probably they have a larger space then rec.709.

Comment: Thank you Giacomo this is very helpful. For my particular purpose, I'm going to store the raw highlight data as LCH and convert to something CSS can understand on the fly